# Redux toolkit redirect without render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect page without render.

Index page

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (!cookie) {
    router.push('/login')
  }
}, []);
```

When I open index page it retain for few second then redirect to login page. Can avoid to render it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useEffect runs **after** the html elements are rendered/added to the DOM.

That's why the index component is being rendered first, and then you are being redirected to login.

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` hook runs at the end of the render cycle. If you would like to redirect ***when*** the component is rendered then conditionally early return render a [`Navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) component to issue a declarative redirect. The component will render at least once.

Example:

```
if (!cookie) {
  return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}

...

return /* normal JSX return */
```